# How to avoid the gray color appearing while scrolling listview with large no of items

Tags: listview, uwp

How do I avoid the default grey color from appearing while loading the list view with large no of items? It's visible when there are lots of items in the list view.

[image: grey color]

Following is my xaml code

```
<StackPanel Name="ccTaskList">
 <ListView Background="#f7f7f9" Visibility="{Binding Path=Show_CC_Close, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}" x:Name="itemListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind TaskList}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource taskTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AllListViewItemStyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: If I just put a ListView on xaml page and add some ListViewItems in it. I did not see the grey color area. So, you might do some customization on your xaml layout. If you do not post your xaml code, we could not help you more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It is fixed when I used incremental loading to load items in listview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/incrementalloadingcollection